# Can I avoid using symbols/strings with Inversifyjs?

Tags: inversifyjs

I want to be able to simply specify what is needed without adding strings or symbols.  This seems to work for declaring the binding:

```
container.bind<Weapon>(Shuriken);
```

But I get a run-time error if I don't use `@inject` and don't know what to put in it when it's being injected:

```
public constructor(
    @inject() weapon: Weapon // compile-time error
) {
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use an interface (I assume that `Weapon` is an interface) you need to ensure that the same ID is used when you declare the binding:

```
container.bind<Weapon>(Shuriken).toSelf();
```

And then you declare the injection:

```
@injectable()
class SomeClass {
    public constructor(
        @inject(Shuriken) weapon: Weapon; // Use the right ID!
    ) {
```

However, using the class removes the benefits of dependency injection. If you want you to use classes you could actually do something more simple:

```
@injectable()
class SomeClass {
    public constructor(
        weapon: Shuriken; // Use the class as Type!
    ) {
```

The recommended solution is to use strings or symbols as IDs:

```
const TYPE = { Weapon: "Weapon" };

container.bind<Weapon>(TYPE.Weapon).to(Shuriken);

@injectable()
class SomeClass {
    public constructor(
        @inject(TYPE.Weapon) weapon: Weapon;
    ) {
```